# DB for Kotlin CLI

Tags: android, kotlin, command-line-interface

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying to create a CLI app that will have all the basic functionalities of
an ecommerce website like having a selection (cateogories, item) and cart. And I need to store the data in a db, I have used mysql for now but i need it to be a standalone app so that i can submit it for testing.

I cannot use SQLite as it uses context and i dont know if i can use context or not. I thought of using firebase but dont know how to embed it(i know how to embed it in android studios by using SHA1 but this is a CLI).

This is my first time creating a CLI app using kotlin please help.

Heres a rough DB structure
[image: DB diagram]

Any help at all will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further details needed.

Comment: What do you mean if you can use 'context' or not? Who is forbidding you from using 'context'?

Comment: its a command line application i just created a folder structure for kotlin and did gradle init, what i mean is, its not on android studios, i dont know if i can get context in a CLI.